# Is that similar software to the kepserverex6 or others ways to connect serial port to mySQL

Tags: mysql, kepserverex

Do have any similar software similar to kepware version 6 that acts as a connection platform to connect the data from the serial port (COM PORT) and send data to the database?
Currently, collect the data using the kepserverex6 and send data to the PHPMyAdmin to visualize the result in various platform...

Or any other possible connection platform or connectivity method used to connect the serial port data to MySQL?

the data coming from the sensors and received by the gateway.

Comment: "...and send data to the PHPMyAdmin". This is definitely wrong, because PhpMyAdmin is just a client tool (for MySQL), and you cannot send data to it. You probably mean that you are sending data to the database.

Answer (score -1):

U can build an OPCUA Client or u can use kepserverex tools;

1. ODBC Client
2. MQTT
3. IOT Gateway